# See the result of a query on the map with Arcgis Api JS

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Let's say you enter these parameters. Which method of the "ArcGISImageServiceLayer" class can serve to display the image of the mosaic dataset? In the attached image the result is an image, but I do not know how to visualize it on the map.
[image: Query]

Part of my code is this, I used the "queryVisibleRasters" method to try to visualize it, but it did not work, any suggestions are very well received, thanks
[image: Code]

Comment: add your rest/layer url  on which you are performing query operation in the question